# Starter was recently replaced but my truck keeps not starting

Tags: ford, starter, ranger

Okay so, my vehicle is a 2003 Ford ranger XLT, 3.0 engine.

Within the last two weeks I had to get the old starter replaced, because it just completely died. I would put the key in, and it would make this quiet electric whining sound, but the engine wouldn't even try to crank. All my lights and radio come on though.

I got the starter replaced, and it worked fine for a few days, except now it's done the same thing twice since then. The first time, I crawled under it and tapped at the starter like the mechanic on the phone told me, and it started up after a few minutes. Except, a week later and it's doing the same thing. I don't understand what's wrong with it. The new starter is just that, new, and I don't want to say the mechanic didn't do his job right, but I'm going out of my mind, and my wallet can't take this.

Comment: Are you sure the starter is 100% new and not a remanufactured unit?

Comment: I bought it new from the AutoZone I started at, pulled it off the shelf myself. Sorry for the delay, at work

Comment: It could very well be you got a bad starter from Autozone. I'd suggest there may be an issue with the solenoid. Try rapping on the solenoid directly this time to see if it helps. This isn't a "sure thing" but might work. Rebuilt starters can be bad right off the shelf. I **always** have them bench tested at the store before leaving. While this isn't fool proof, it's at least a good start to know it runs before you go to the effort of putting them on the vehicle. Since you work at the Autozone, I'd suggest you offer this to all of your customers, for starters and alternators.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't been able to try it yet, getting a lift home so I can poke at it. I'm definitely going to offer the bench test to all of my customers from now on, because this is ridiculous. You've been immensely helpful!

Comment: AutoZone electrical parts are crap, I stopped using them.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind "off the shelf" does NOT mean new, especially with car parts. "Remanufactured" and "rebuilt" parts are very common, and their quality varies considerably not only from one supplier to the other, but also from one box to the other.

Get your starter tested, and do check the electrical connections for corrosion.